# Extract PHP variables from one line separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql, variables

i'm storing data in a database column like this.

```
1920,1927,3772,6127,3671
```

and i want to extract this value to variable as many as they are.

```
$var1 = 1920
$var2= 1927
$var3= 3772
$var4= 6127
$var5= 3671
```

and automatically read any new value WHILE there is "," comma and add it to a new var

Comment: Don't store lists of data in a single column in a database. As you can see already, that makes it difficult to process. Read up on normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$vars = '1920,1927,3772,6127,3671';

$array_vars = explode(",",$vars);
foreach($array_vars as $key => $value){
    ${'var' . $key} = $value;
}
echo $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function

```
$values = "1920,1927,3772,6127,3671";
$split_to_var = explode(',', $values);
$var1 = $split_to_var[0] ; // first one
echo $var1; // Returns 1920
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). something like below

```
$str = '1920,1927,3772,6127,3671';
$arr = explode(',' , $str);
//var_dump($arr);
```

For accessing the values use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($arr as $val){
    //echo $val;
}
```

or

```
$var1 = $arr[0];
$var2 = $arr[1];
$var3 = $arr[2];
$var4 = $arr[3];
$var5 = $arr[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good idea to store them like this, but you can do it with `explode`.

```
$ar = explode(',',$initial_var);
```

Now you have the `$ar` array with all values and you can access them as `$ar[1], $ar[2]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad relational database technique to store information in this way. Break it into a separate table with a foreign key. This will make querying a lot easier and you won't have to worry about breaking up the string.